# Debug Javascript with multi-level source maps

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, google-chrome-devtools, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I have a lot of javascript files, which goes through grunt uglify and gets minified individually, and further, I am performing grunt concat on these to get a single bundled minified file with source map.

**Ex.**

> a.js, b.js, c.js `->`
>    Uglify `->` a.min.js, b.min.js,c.min.js `->` concat `->` bundle.min.js

With dev tools and source map, from bundle.min.js, I can trace back only up to a.min.js/b.min.js/c.min.js. **Where as my goal is to use source map to trace back up to a.js/b.js/c.js.**

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement can be achieved, however you'll need to change the order of your tasks to the following instead:

---

`a.js, b.js, c.js` `-->` **concat** `-->` `bundle.js` `-->` **uglify** `-->` `bundle.min.js`

---

Note: The order of the tasks has been changed to *concatenate* the individual `.js` files before *uglifying* the resultant output.

**Why is it necessary to change the order of tasks?**

Because [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) provides the [`sourceMapIn`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#sourcemapin) option, whilst [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) simply doesn't. Besides it's typical practice to *concatenate* files before *uglifying* them.

The `sourceMapIn` option is described as follows:

> **sourceMapIn**
>
> Type: `String Function`
>
> Default: `undefined`
>
> The location of an input source map from an earlier compilation, e.g. from CoffeeScript. If a function is provided, the uglify source is passed as the argument and the return value will be used as the sourceMap name. This only makes sense when there's one source file.

**Gruntfile.js**

Your `Gruntfile.js` can be configured something like this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      options: {
        // ...
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceMapName: 'dist/js/bundle.map' // Specify path/name for sourceMap
      },
      my_target: {
        src: ['src/js/a.js', 'src/js/b.js', 'src/js/c.js'],
        dest: 'dist/js/bundle.js',
      },
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        // ...
        sourceMap: {
          includeSources: true
        },
        sourceMapIn: 'dist/js/bundle.map', // Specify the same path/name as
                                           // the `sourceMapName` value
                                           // in the `concat` task
      },
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'dist/js/bundle.min.js': ['dist/js/bundle.js']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Note we run the `concat` task before the `uglify` task.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:my_target', 'uglify:my_target']);
};
```

**Notes:**

1. The path value specified for the `concat.options.sourceMapName` and `uglify.options.sourceMapIn` must be the same, e.g. `dist/js/bundle.map`.
2. The `concat` task must run before the `uglify` task.
3. The `src` and `dest` paths for both tasks will need to be defined as per your projects requirements.